# Changing background image wbkit with jquery

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, webkit, background-image

This code works on mozilla but doesn't work on chrome and safari, why?

```
$('#id').css('background-image','url(/image.png)');
```

Comment: Works just fine in my Chrome ?

Comment: It doesn't work, go on www.2lol.ro and click the down arrow in the header using mozilla, the background-image will change after click, but with google chrome and safari it will not.

Comment: Not 100% sure but try backgroundImage instead of background-image

Comment: Billy Moat, i tried and still wont work.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this way:

```
$('#id').css('background-image','url("/image.png")');
```

Comment: Yes, because it work's in mozilla. Go on http://2lol.ro/ and click the down arrow from the header using mozilla firefox.